# Migrating keras.backend.conv2d from Keras 1.x to 2.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, theano, keras-2

I'm migrating a project from Keras 1.x to 2.x.

In the code, a [`keras.backend.conv2d`](https://keras.io/backend/#conv2d) operation that was running fine in 1.x now crashes in 2.x.

```
convs = K.conv2d(a, b, padding='valid', data_format='channels_first')
```

Input tensors shapes `a` and `b` are both `(1024, 4, 1, 1)` and output tensor shape was `(1024, 1024, 1, 1)` in 1.x.

With 2.x I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: CorrMM: impossible output shape
  bottom shape: 1024 x 4 x 1 x 1
  weights shape: 1 x 1 x 1024 x 4
  top shape: 1024 x 1 x -1022 x -2

Apply node that caused the error: CorrMM{valid, (1, 1), (1, 1), 1 False}(Print{message='a', attrs=('__str__',), global_fn=<function DEBUG_printTensorShape at 0x00000272EF1FAD08>}.0, Subtensor{::, ::, ::int64, ::int64}.0)
Toposort index: 30
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, (False, False, True, True)), TensorType(float32, (True, True, False, False))]
Inputs shapes: [(1024, 4, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1024, 4)]
```

I'm using Theano backend, and set `channels_first` both in `K.set_image_data_format` and `conv2d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `conv2D` method, `a` is the actual image, and `b` is the kernel.

---

The expected shape for `a` is (with "channels_first"):

```
(batchSize, channels, side1, side2)
```

So, your input has:

- 1024 images
- 4 channels
- image 1 x 1

---

But although using `'channels_last'`, the expected shape for `b` is:

```
(side1,side2, inputChannels,outputChannels)
```

This seems a little misleading, because in the filters, it is still channels last. (Tested on my keras, version 2.0.4)

So, if your output was `(1024,1024,1,1)`, I assume `b` should have 1024 output filters, so it should be shaped as:

```
(1,1,4,1024)
```

You should probably use some method to permute the dimensions, not just reshape. Numpy has `swapaxes` and keras has `K.permute_dimensions`.

Comment: `K.permute_dimensions(x, (3,2,1,0))` did the job. Thanks !